# JaCoCo successfully profiles all Java projects, Sonar only finds coverage in one

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I am using Sonar 3.2 + Java 1.6 + Ant 1.7 0 JBoss 1.5. We have many Java projects and Ant compiles them into one build project which also contains the .ear file, java classes, etc. I have started JBoss server by giving the JaCoCo agent as a parameter to the JBoss JVM. Looking at the jacoco.exec file with a text editor, it contains traces from all our Java projects (as expected).

However, when importing the jacoco.exec file into Sonar, it only displays IT code coverage for one of our java projects. In the Sonar Ant configuration I include all our project java source and class files. These seem to be imported fine since violations are displayed for all java sources.

What could be wrong? Btw. what files does Sonar compare the jacoco.exec coverage file against, java source files or compiled class files? I have included both though...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, for me it was caused by a bug in the sonar-jacoco-plugin. Version 1.2 had a bug so that it only included the first binary directory.

This is fixed in version 1.3 of the sonar-jacoco-plugin.

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-164 for details.